# How to put shiny inline radiobuttons text at the top

Tags: css, r, shiny

I would like to create a rating site, just like this:
https://codepen.io/migli/pen/xGRwje

But I want at the midle.

```
div(radioButtons("nav1", "", choiceValues=1:10, 
choiceNames=as.character(1:10), selected=0, inline = T), align='center'),
```

This is that I want in the midle, but i am bad in css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(shiny)

css <- "
.radio-inline {
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}
.radio-inline input {
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px !important;
}"

ui <- basicPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(css))
  ),
  radioButtons("nav1", "", choiceValues = 1:10, 
               choiceNames = as.character(1:10), selected = 0, inline = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Friend! So amazing!

Answer (score 2):

See this I have added a div wrapper around form and following css will make it center vertically and horizontally

```css
.makeItCenter {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="makeItCenter">
 your code
 </div>
```

check the below link
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vPXPmg

screenshot:
[image: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vPXPmg]

Comment: Thank you, I want to use it in shiny,  and currently can not maki it to work, The code is great, thanks but it not works inside shiny, for me. Do you know shiny?

Comment: Am not sure what shiny is can you point me to it so that I can update the answer as per that

Comment: Itt made really center everything but the labels are on the left

Answer (score 0):

Surround your whole form with a div, let's call it "rate":

```
<div id="rate">
    Your code here
</div>
```

and then in your css file, add this:

```
#rate
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```